# Is it fine to use sizeof operator in snprintf

Tags: c

Is it fine to use sizeof operator with  "snprintf" ?
for example

```
   char cstring[20];
   snprintf(cstring,sizeof(cstring),"%s","somestring......");
```

Comment: You have tagged your question with `c++`.  Actually, in C++, we wouldn't use `snprintf` if all possible but rather use an `std::ostringstream`.  If you are merely interested in the C solution, please consider removing the `c++` tag.

Comment: Why do you think it would not be fine?

Comment: @EdHeal it looks fine to me but just want to confirm (does any body faced any issue in any platform)

Comment: @EdHeal I wasn't sure either, because `cstring` isn't initialized. So according to my almost non-existent C++ knowledge, `sizeof(cstring)` could be either `0`, `20` or undefined.

Comment: @EricDuminil - Its size does not depend on its contents

Comment: @EdHeal okay. But for example, `strlen` would, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's fine, the specific case you posted is good except that you don't check the return value, so you won't know if the string was truncated.

Comment: @TimHarper: It depends on the application.  In some security sensitive applications, truncating a string could lead to a breach of security, so not checking the return value could be even worse than a segmentation fault.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you're saying there are times where it is better to allow OOB writes in some security sensitive applications?

Comment: @TimHarper: I am saying that both truncation and OOB writes potentially have security implications, and we can't know in advance which one is "better."  Neither is better, they are both horrible.

Answer (score 5):

It is fine in example you posted.

However, it's not fine in any case where array decays in to pointer:

```
void func(char s []) {
    snprintf(s,sizeof(s),"%s","somestring......"); // Not fine, s is actually pointer
}
int main(void) {
    char cstring[20];
    func(cstring); // Array decays to pointer
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `sizeof` operator in the `snprintf`, but if the length of the string is bigger than the size which you have specified, then the remaining characters in the string will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use. But if the string is higher than the sizeof value then the string is truncated. or up to the given value is stored in that array.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                            
int main()                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                             
        char str[16];                                                                                                                         
        int len;                                                                                                                              

        len = snprintf(str, sizeof( str ), "%s %d %f", "hello world", 1000, 10.5);                                                            
        printf("%s\n", str);                                                                                                                  

        if (len >= 16)                                                                                                                        
        {                                                                                                                                     
                printf("length truncated (from %d)\n", len);                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                                     
} 

output:
=======
 ./a.out
hello world 100
length truncated (from 26)

/* You can see from the output only 15 char + '\0' is displayed on the console ( stored in the str ) */


/* Now changing the size of the str from 16 to 46 */

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

        char str[46];
        int len;

        len = snprintf(str, sizeof( str ), "%s %d %f", "hello world", 1000, 10.5);
        printf("%s\n", str);

        if (len >= 46)
        {
                printf("length truncated (from %d)\n", len);
        }
}

output:
==========
./a.out
hello world 1000 10.500000
```